# Django how to make timezone aware CustomTimeField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
from django.db import models


class CustomTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    ....
```

- **Goal:** I need to store the date in form of datetime but I need this field to return only the hour:minute:second and eliminate the rest. **If you can do it in the Custom Field or in the serializer both will be great**

Comment: can you show the serializer setup that you have tried?

Comment: I changed mind I find out that it is fine to do it in the serializers so if you have an idea how to do it there that will be great

Answer (score 2):

well I don't think that changing the behaviour of the field would be a good idea. instead, you can define a virtual field that returns the time in you favourite format and use that in your serializer.

your model:

```
class AModel(models.Modle):
    date_time_field = models.DateTimeField()
    
    @property
    def custom_time(self):
        return self.date_time_field.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

your serializer:

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_time = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ('custom_time',)
```

Comment: `read_only=True`! this can handle `GET`requests but how to handle `POST` requests?